# Laravel 5 exception "The Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils::escapeArgument() is deprecated"

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, windows-10, laravel-5.4

I get everytime `ErrorException` when I want to execute any command using `artisan`, `phpunit`.

How can I fix it?

```
The Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils::escapeArgument() method is deprecated since version 3.3 and will be removed in 4.0. Use a command line array or give env vars to the Process::start/run() method instead. C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\symfony\process\ProcessUtils.php:43
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:68
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:89
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule.php:69
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\app\Console\Kernel.php:28
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:101
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:86
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:827
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:776
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php:17
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:208
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:267
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\tests\CreatesApplication.php:18
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php:89
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php:66
C:\xampp\htdocs\mee2\tests\TestCase.php:15
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "adamwathan/bootforms": "^0.8.4",
        "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^7.0",
        "laracasts/utilities": "^2.1",
        "laravel/dusk": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelista/ekko": "^1.3",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
        "sentry/sentry": "^1.6",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.6.1",
        "sofa/model-locking": "~5.3",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^5.8",
        "spatie/laravel-migrate-fresh": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-model-cleanup": "^1.2",
        "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/functions.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Laravel 5 is on xampp, php 7, apache, windows 10

I don't have the same problem on other computer with the same installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still have this issue, I was able to resolve it by updating my php.ini file. It was an xdebug setting I had that was conflicting and causing the issue.

I had:

`xdebug.scream = 1`

I changed it to:

`xdebug.scream = 0`

Now everything runs as expected.

If you don't have xdebug, try searching for: `scream.enabled` and changing it from:

`scream.enabled=1`

to:

`scream.enabled=0`

Comment: In my case it's in **/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini**

Comment: Thanks, This is a valid solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `composer update` in your project folder?

Comment: Sure. It didn't help I had to manually change file in vendor directory